# ghci cabal sandbox flags for Emacs Haskell inferior mode

Tags: haskell, emacs, ghci

I would like GHCI to have the local cabal sandbox in scope when I work in emacs.
From bash, the syntax is as follows:

`ghci -no-user-package-db -package-db .cabal-sandbox/*-packages.conf.d`

I add the flags to inf-haskell.el , within the definition of `haskell-program-name`, as follows:

```el
(defcustom haskell-program-name
  (or (cond
   ((executable-find "hugs") "hugs \"+.\"")
   ((executable-find "ghci") "ghci -no-user-package-db -package-db .cabal-sandbox/*-packages.conf.d"))
  "hugs \"+.\"")
  "The name of the command to start the inferior Haskell process.
   The command can include arguments."
   ;; Custom only supports the :options keyword for a few types, e.g. not
   ;; for string.
   ;; :options '("hugs \"+.\"" "ghci")
      :group 'inferior-haskell
      :type '(choice string (repeat string)))
```

but it doesn't seem to work, i.e. after reloading emacs, inspecting the value with `C-h v haskell-program-name` just shows it equal to `"ghci"`, and the packages I need are of course not in scope.
Any pointers? Thanks!

Comment: You should use `cabal repl` instead of manually starting ghci with a sandbox and configure emacs to use cabal repl with `(custom-set-variables '(haskell-process-type 'cabal-repl))`

Comment: Thanks for the good idea, but this also implies setting up a cabal project for every little script. I just wanted to try out a few libraries which I couldn't get to install globally. Cabal hell, you know

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of fighting, we finally figured it out: [relevant Github issue](https://github.com/haskell/haskell-mode/issues/398)

If you have `haskell-process-type` set to `auto`, and have the latest (>= 1.20.x) `cabal-install` in your path, running `C-c C-l` will open a cabal repl in emacs (even if you don't have a .cabal file around) and detect your sandbox. This lets you throw down a sandbox, quickly install a library, and then toy around with it interactively in emacs.

Good luck!

Comment: good Sir, you are a true gentleman. I will look into this as soon as I get back to my box.

Comment: Alas, no. I have cabal-install 1.20.0.3, and this is my `init.el` configuration:

    (autoload 'ghc-init "ghc" nil t)
    (autoload 'ghc-debug "ghc" nil t)
    (add-hook 'haskell-mode-hook (lambda () (ghc-init)))
    (custom-set-variables '(haskell-process-type 'auto))

    (add-hook 'after-init-hook #'global-flycheck-mode)

Comment: hi @fosskers, unfortunately I cannot reproduce. My problem is specifically with the GUI version of Emacs, but the in-terminal one works as expected.
I don't understand this inconsistency, since both version use the same init.el

Comment: What exactly is failing with the GUI version?